# Is this correct: I benefit of Xxx’s message to inform you

Tags: translation

Someone uses heavily google translate to write messages.

There are a lot of bad translations, but I'm wondering if this one is correct:

> I benefit of Xx's message to inform you than me and myself think I
> speak english better than native people.

Wouldn't it be better if it was something like:

In addition to Xx's message, I would like to inform you that...

Comment: To make sense of the sentence you have quoted we first need to have a better idea of what the person really had in mind when writing it. It seems a bit far-fetched for someone who uses Google translate regularly to be claiming that they speak English better than native speakers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No the first sentence wrong and makes no sense! And yes you are right to say the sentence is supposed to be:

> In addition to X's message, I would like to inform you that I speak english better than native people.

Comment: This is, in my opinion, a proofreading question, and therefore off-topic for this site.

Comment: Where should I ask this question then?

Comment: @OlivierPons - try Reddit, maybe?